How to prevent WM_CHAR for keypresses handled by WM_KEYDOWN?
I've written a custom Windows control that processes WM_CHAR messages for text input and WM_KEYDOWN messages for "navigation" keystrokes from keys like the arrows, Delete, Home, etc.
I would like my control to process the '+' and '-' keys on the numeric keypad as navigation keys.  They are distinguishable from the regular '=+' and '-_' keys on the main portion of the keyboard because they have unique virtual key codes (VK_ADD and VK_SUBTRACT), so processing them in my WM_KEYDOWN works fine.
The problem, of course, is that the control also receives WM_CHAR messages for those keystrokes, because the TranslateMessage call in the message loop treats them like regular keys that generate text.  Since my control is in a library that may be used by various applications, the message loop is out of scope.
Therefore, my WM_CHAR handler needs to be able to distinguish between '+' and '-' characters generated from the main keyboard and those from the numeric keypad so that it could ignore the latter ones.
But the character code in a WM_CHAR is indeed a character code and no longer the virtual key code.  I tried checking the "extended key" bit in metadata, but apparently these are not extended keys.
That leaves the scan code.  The WM_CHAR documentation says the scan codes vary from OEM to OEM.  But the Keyboard Input Overview documentation suggests that the scan codes were standardized in the HID specification.
Can I trust that I'll always get a HID scan code?
The codes generated from my Microsoft keyboard do match the HID values, but the conflict in the documentation makes me wonder whether I can actually rely on that for other machines.
My fallback solution would be to have my control note when it processes a VK_ADD or VK_SUBTRACT so that it can know to ignore the next WM_CHAR with a corresponding '+' or '-'.

Not picking on anyone in particular, but I I wish folks would stop adding markup to my posts.  I intentionally mark text as code only when it's actually code—statements and expressions—and not to the names of identifiers (unless absolutely necessary to resolve ambiguity).  This is especially true when writing about APIs, like Microsoft's, that capitalize all identifiers, allowing them to work naturally as proper nouns.  I find SO's heavy styling for inline code distractingly hard-to-read, so I prefer to use it only when necessary.

You could try using GetKeyState() to see if the keypad keys are down when you get the WM_CHAR message (and ignore them if so).

Both WM_KEYDOWN and WM_CHAR give you the scan code which generated the messages, so it should not be hard to ignore WM_CHAR messages for scan codes that have already sent you WM_KEYDOWN messages for VK_ADD etc, regardless of whether the scan codes are standardized or not. Scan codes don't change while a keyboard is active.
For example, try something like this:
bool wIgnoredScanCodes[256] = {};

...

switch (uMsg)
{
    case WM_KEYDOWN: {
        if (wParam == VK_ADD) {
            BYTE bScanCode = (lParam >> 16) & 0xFF;
            wIgnoredScanCodes[bScanCode] = true;
        }
        ...
        break;
    }

    case WM_CHAR: {
        BYTE bScanCode = (lParam >> 16) & 0xFF;
        if (!wIgnoredScanCodes[bScanCode]) {
            ...
        }
        break;
    }
}

However, there could be multiple keyboards attached to the machine (rare, but possible), and there is no way to distinguish between them in the WM_KEY... and WM_CHAR messages.  So, it is possible that one keyboard could use a given scan code for VK_ADD etc, and another keyboard uses the same scan code for some other purpose.  If you need to make this distinction, then you will have to use the Raw Input API instead, which provides you with a per-device identifier in the WM_INPUT message.

Thanks for the sanity check.  In my actual use case, it's a runtime decision whether a particular use of VK_ADD should be treated as a navigation key or a text key, so I'll have to keep setting and clearing the ignored scan codes.  I know TranslateMessage posts the WM_CHAR just before a WM_KEYDOWN is about to be dispatched, so it will arrive after the WM_KEYDOWN, which is great.  But will it always arrive before the next WM_KEYDOWN.  And I wonder whether I'll need to track repeat counts, too.

"it's a runtime decision whether a particular use of VK_ADD should be treated as a navigation key or a text key" - that sounds very brittle and error-prone. You should edit your question to explain why you want this behavior.

My control is a grid of cells.  It provides default behaviors for common operations, like scrolling if the user hits PageDown or putting the selected cell into edit mode if the user types text.  The grid notifies its parent "user hit this navigation key" or "user typed text", and the parent responds "ignore it" or "do the default behavior".  Whether VK_ADD is a navigation command or an attempt to type text is an application decision outside the grid's purview.  If the app says "ignore it", the grid must filter the corresponding WM_CHAR message that has already been posted.

That kind of filtering should be done in the message loop instead. Have the loop check if the grid control is in focus and if so then ask it about the WM_KEYDOWN, and if the message should be ignored then simply discard it right there and not pass it along to TranslateMessage() to post the WM_CHAR.

It's a UI control in a library used by multiple applications, and sometimes on a modal dialog box.  The message loop is out-of-scope.  Besides, I've already got it working.  As long as the application's message loop isn't using the filters in GetMessage or PeekMessage, it appears I can rely on the corresponding WM_CHAR to arrive before the next WM_KEYDOWN.

"it appears I can rely on the corresponding WM_CHAR to arrive before the next WM_KEYDOWN" - I'm not sure how reliable that can actually be. If the application is slow to process messages, and a user holds a key down, for instance, I can imagine subsequent WM_KEYDOWN messages being posted before the 1st WM_CHAR is posted. So, you will likely have to pay attention to the repeat count as well as the scan code. I still think you should edit your question to provide more detail and context about the specific problem you are trying to solve. There maybe a different/better solution.
